# docker networking aliases within multiple docker-compose files

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I'm having an issue with docker networking. Here is my scenario:

I have two docker projects:

caipora/
docker-compose.yml
classificacao/
docker-compose.yml

on the caipora docker-compose.yml file i have:

```
version: '3.5'
networks:
    pge:
      name: pge
      driver: bridge

services:
  
  caipora:
    build:
      context: ./caipora-sso/build/docker/
    container_name: caipora
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/caipora:/caipora
    networks:
      - pge

  proxy:
    image: nginx
    container_name: proxy
    mem_limit: 128m
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
        - ./config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        - ./config/nginx.htpasswd:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.htpasswd 
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
    networks:
      - pge
```

and on my nginx.conf from the caipora folder:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    upstream lineu{
        server frontend:3000;
    }
    upstream default{
        server caipora:8080;
    }
    server {

     listen *:80  default_server; 
     server_name homologacao.sistemas.pge.pi.gov.br;
    client_max_body_size 0;

    set  $allowOriginSite *;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires off;
    etag off;

    root /var/www/html;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        autoindex on;
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location /lineu {
        proxy_pass         http://lineu/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
    location / {

        set $accept_language "pt-br";
        proxy_pass         http://default;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
    }
}
```

and, finally, the docker-compose from the classificacao folder:

```
version: '3.5'
networks:
    pge:
      name: pge
      external: true

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./classificacao-frontend
    container_name: frontend
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - pge
```

Now with the problem:

In nginx.conf, i proxy_pass the /lineu url to the frontend container by the container name, so i don't have to expose ports. This works at first, as the proxy container can sucessfully resolve frontend to the container's ip. But if i restart the frontend container or the entire docker-compose project from the classificacao folder, the frontend container ip changes, and the nginx proxy container, located in another docker-compose file, still sees frontend as the previous ip address and won't resolve to the new ip unless i restart the proxy container.

Is there a way to solve this? Like forcing the proxy container to restart if i restart the frontend container, or "link" those two projects (without joining the two docker-compose.yml files).

Comment: This sounds like a long-standing bug in Nginx, where it caches DNS results indefinitely and doesn't respect DNS TTLs.  In a non-Docker context, see for example [NGINX is not respecting DNS TTL of Upstream Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/1105249/nginx-is-not-respecting-dns-ttl-of-upstream-server).  You probably have to forcibly restart the proxy here.

Comment: Is [this](https://serverfault.com/a/593003/27515) at all relevant to the problem?

Comment: unfortunately no, i think it's more related to NGINX from the previous comment.